# Limit of a time dependent series.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I have the following problem.

Let $\sum_{n}c_{n}(t)$ be a bounded series, in particular $c_{n}(t)>0$ for all $t>0$ and $n$ and $\sum_{n}c_{n}(t)<1 $ for all $t>0$ . Furthermore, assume the following

$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n}c_{n}(t) = 0
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n}\sqrt{c_{n}(t)}<1 \;\; (\forall t>0).
$$

I would like to show that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n}\sqrt{c_{n}(t)} = 0 
$$

What I Have tried: I have considered using DCT and WMT theorems but to no avail. The issue I have is that I do not have an explicit form for the $c_{n}$ so I can not dominate this sequence in order to apply the Wierstrass M test and or the Dominated convergence theorem. I have also considered the monotone convergence theorem but this does not work since I have no assumptions regarding monotonicity. Nevertheless, it seems that this problem should be provable; I am just not having any luck. Approaching it by contradiction and showing that there will be an infinite amount of $t>0$ such that at least one $c_{n}(t)$ is infinitely often bounded away from zero seems like the only path but I would rather not prove by contradiction. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to prove is not correct. To find a counterexample, we consider the corresponding problem for inifinite integrals: taking $\sqrt{c_n(t)}$ as a function $f_t(x)$, then the statement in OP corresponds to:

> **Model problem.** If $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\int_0^\infty |f_t(x)|^2\,dx=0$, and $\int_0^\infty f_t(x)\,dx<1$, then do we have $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\int_0^\infty f_t(x)\,dx=0$?

The answer to the model problem is NO: Let $f\in(0,1/2)$ be a decreasing function such that $0<\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx<1/2$, then take $f_t(x)=\frac1{1+t}f(x/(1+t))$. In this way, we have $\int_0^\infty |f_t(x)|^2\,dx=\frac1{1+t}\int_0^\infty |f(x)|^2\,dx\to0$ as $t\to+\infty$. But $\int_0^\infty f_t(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ for all $t>0$.

Now we back to the original series case. Let $c_n(t)=|f_t(n)|^2$ for $n\geq 0$. Since $f_t$ is decreasing, using the ideas of [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) we obtain
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(t)\leq |f_t(0)|^2+\int_1^\infty |f_t(x-1)|^2\,dx\to0,\qquad t\to+\infty.$$
Also, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt{c_n(t)}\leq f_t(0)+\int_1^\infty f_t(x-1)\,dx=\frac1{1+t}f(0)+\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx<1.$$
However,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt{c_n(t)}\geq \int_0^\infty f_t(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx,\qquad \forall t>0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. This clears everything up!

Comment: @Hldngpk You're welcome. Glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to prove appears to be false.  Let
$$\sqrt{c_n(t)}=\frac{e^{-t}}{2}(1-e^{-t})^n\text{,}$$
so that
$$c_n(t)=\frac{e^{-2t}}{4}(1-e^{-t})^{2n}\text{,}$$
then
$$\sum_{n} \sqrt{c_n(t)} = \frac{ \frac{e^{-t}}{2} }{ e^{-t} } = \frac{1}{2}\text{,}$$

while
$$\sum_{n} c_n(t) = \frac{ \frac{e^{-2t}}{4} }{ 1 - (1-e^{-t})^2 } = \frac{ \frac{e^{-2t}}{4} }{ 2e^{-t}-e^{-2t} } = \frac{ \frac{e^{-t}}{4} }{ 2-e^{-t} }\to 0 \text{.}$$

##### Remark

In case it’s a little mysterious where the preceding counterexample came from, let me say a little about how to think about a problem like this.

The variable $t$ plays almost no role in the problem, in the sense that $c_n(t)$ and $c_n(t’)$ have no prescribed relationship for $t\neq t’$.  Instead $t$ is only relevant in the limiting process.

So really, the question is more or less asserting (with a few not too relevant extra conditions) that if $\sum_n c_n$ gets arbitrarily small, then so must $\sum_n \sqrt{c_n}$.

This smells like a lie that would be contradicted even by geometric series, and so you just demand that a series $\sum_n a r^n=\frac{a}{1-r}=k<1$ for some constant $k$ and check to see if that still gives you the freedom to make $\sum_n a^2 r^{2n}$ as small as you want.  Once you see that it does (as $r\to 1$), you build the explicit counterexample from that, writing r as a function of $t$.

Comment: Fantastic counter-example. Thank you kindly for your time.

Comment: @Hldngpk thanks, glad I could help, added a little clarification to explain where it all came from in case that helps.